# Adding panels programatically based on .top is being based on the scroll of its parent

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for some assistance in fixing an issue. At the moment I have developed some code that adds a user control to a panel. It adds multiple user controls to the panel and does this based on the .top feature. However, once the panel that I am adding the user controls to is scrolled down the user controls seem to be placed strangely.

I have already tried to adjust the .top value but I am not sure how to do it in relation to the scroll of the panel.

```
int i = 0;
foreach(memberInformation mi in pnlMembers.Controls.OfType<memberInformation>()) 
{
    try
    {
        if (UserInformation.isPartyLeader)
        {
            mi.canUserEdit = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            mi.canUserEdit = "false";
        }
        mi.playerName = downloadInfo.Split(':')[i].Split(',')[0];
        mi.playerRole = downloadInfo.Split(':')[i].Split(',')[1];
     }
     catch
     {
         pnlMembers.Controls.Remove(mi);
     }
     i++;
}
```

VIDEO to show what is happening:   https://gyazo.com/985566afb7e4bab464dd06da191a0710
https://gyazo.com/4b0514cbdb310ea8abc46a397458130c

Comment: I think you could add your UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel instead. It will layout the UCs for you.

Comment: Try commenting out the code in the "catch" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way in order to position panels inside another panel is to use flowlayoutpanel.
Thanks